# Why do I need a reference for unused type in overloaded method?

Tags: c#, overloading

I've got a dll with two functions, ex.:

```
public int Add(int a, int b){
  //...
}

public int Add(ComplexType complexType){
  //...
}
```

I reference that dll in another project, where I call just the first one:

```
var result = Add(2, 3)
```

Why am I getting an error that "ComplexType" in undefined and I need to reference dll with "ComplexType" definition, which I'm not using here. I couldn't find any explanation of such behaviour.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: The compiler has to, *in general*, be able to assess all data types in *all* overloads, *before* it can decide which method it's actually trying to invoke.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN The type 'ComplexType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'X'

Comment: There are multiple duplicates of this question: short story: Make the overloads have different names or make one be non-public if you want to use just one without referencing assemblies of types passed to other overloads.